# What is the number of significant figures in $6*(7.203)**2$?

Tags: conventions, error-analysis

My textbook says:

> "In multiplication or division, the final
> result should retain as many significant
> figures as are there in the original number
> with the least significant figures."

but it also says $6*(7.203)**2$ has four significant figures. Shouldn't it be one, considering the above rule?

Answer (score 1):

The book is right because “6” by convention means *exactly* six (i.e., 6.000000... to infinite precision). “6.” would mean “approximately six, to one significant digit”, in which case you would be right.

Comment: And of course, the exponent 2 is similarly accurate.